# Explaining the math behind an algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

Given a sorted array of integers a, find such an integer x that the value of

abs(a[0] - x) + abs(a[1] - x) + ... + abs(a[a.length - 1] - x)
is the smallest possible (here abs denotes the absolute value).
If there are several possible answers, output the smallest one.

Example

For a = [2, 4, 7], the output should be
absoluteValuesSumMinimization(a) = 4.

I was able to solve this by brute forcing it but then i came upon this

```
function absoluteValuesSumMinimization(A) {
    return A[Math.ceil(A.length/2)-1];
}
```

looking to learn how/why this works.

Comment: isn't it because the average value over the entire array is going to end up being closest to the median, so then each term is close to zero?

Comment: I doubt that will actually give you the answer...

Comment: As a hint, `Math.ceil(A.length/2)-1` is just calculating the middle index of the array, so `return A[Math.ceil(A.length/2)-1]` is saying that the correct integer `x` you are looking for is the median element of the array. Does this make sense intuitively? Try writing down some arrays and seeing if it pieces together.

Comment: The reason why this works is explained here: [The median minimizes the sum of absolute deviations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations)

Comment: Since the list is sorted, that function is pretty much returning the median (except when there is an even number of elements in the list, in which case it is returning the smallest number in the list that is closest to the median). If x is close to the smallest value in the list, then for the higher values in the list you'll end up with big values for abs(a[m] - x) for some m < a.length, and vice versa. Kind of makes sense intuitively.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question, answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down.

`A.length/2` returns half the length, used to find the middle of the array. For even-length arrays, this will be to the right of the middle. For odd-length arrays, it'll be the middle.

`Math.ceil(A.length/2)` rounds up if necessary, so the middle of an array of 5 would be 2.5 -> 3. This makes the odd-length arrays off by one.

`Math.ceil(A.length/2)-1` goes down one index. This corrects off-by-one errors for all the arrays.

All this solution is saying is that in an array of even length, the value you're looking for will *always* be to the left of the middle. In an array of odd length, it will *always* be the middle item.

This makes sense intuitively. Subtracting the middle item in the array from each item will always result in the lowest sum. In an even length array, the two center items will always result in an identical sum, so the lowest number will be to the left of the center.

To see this, remove the `console.log` comment from this brute-force solution and try several arrays:

```
function absoluteValuesSumMinimization(ints) {
  const vals = [];

  ints.forEach(int => {
    const sum = ints.reduce((accum, next) => {
      return accum + Math.abs(next  - int);
    }, 0);

    vals.push(sum);
  });

  // console.log(vals);
  const lowest = Math.min(...vals);
  return ints[vals.indexOf(lowest)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The solution you provided was very similar to what I used but the explanation definitely helps me understand the one liner.

Answer (score 1):

We can write the problem as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IFXP.jpg

When we factor out the N, the first term becomes the average of the list "a":

N (mean(a) - a<sub>j</sub>)

If we assume that the list of sorted, then the value that will minimize this quantity is the value that is closest to the term mean(a), which is the median of the list.

Math.ceil(A.length/2)-1 simply returns the middle value of the list, which is the median of a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have n<sub>1</sub> values where `a[i] - x` is negative and n<sub>2</sub> values where `a[i] - x` is positive.

If we increase the integer `x` by one, then the sum of the absolute values increases by n<sub>1</sub> - n<sub>2</sub>.

If we decrease the integer `x` by one, the total sum of the absolute values increases by n<sub>2</sub> - n<sub>1</sub>.

Therefore, as long as n<sub>1</sub> and n<sub>2</sub> are not equal, we can decrease the total sum of absolute values by moving `x` in one direction or the other, depending on whether n<sub>1</sub> - n<sub>2</sub> is positive or negative.

Thus, at the minimum it is necessary to have n<sub>1</sub> = n<sub>2</sub>, *i.e.* there need to be same as many `a[i]` values smaller than `x` as there are larger than `x`.